# How to check PDF-A 1b compliance with open source tools?

Tags: java, pdf, open-source, pdfa

How can i check (and additionally create) PDF-A 1b compliant PDF documents using open source tools? Does anybody know an open source tool?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Duplicate of [Convert to PDF/A and check compliance under Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464539/convert-to-pdf-a-and-check-compliance-under-linux)

Comment: Or of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569129/how-can-i-test-a-pdf-document-if-it-is-pdf-a-compliant

Answer (score 1):

Try with http://www.lowagie.com/iText/. It can recognize the version of the loaded PDF and can create PDF as well. It is open source, but I'm not sure do they support exactly the version of the PDF you mention.

Comment: @m_pGladiator: *"checking the version of the loaded PDF"* amounts to reading the first 8 bytes of a file only. I can create a PDF-1.7 easily and declare it to be PDF-1.2 by changing 1 Byte in the first line so it reads `%PDF-1.2`. This does not mean it indeed limits itself to the file format features of Acrobat 3 now. Same for PDF/A-1b: a file must be able to successfully pass a substantial compliance test, otherwise it is a fake PDF/A file, not a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

Or try [www.validatepdfa.com](http://www.validatepdfa.com) - not open source but 100% free online validator.