# How can I test a PDF document if it is PDF/A compliant?

Tags: validation, pdf, test-suite, pdfa

We write a software that create PDF files. How we can check if the resulting pdf files are PDF/A compatible? Are there any test suite for it available?

Comment: Some context for people unfamiliar with PDF/A: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464539/convert-to-pdf-a-and-check-compliance-under-linux

Comment: http://www.access-for-all.ch/en/pdf-lab/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac/downloading-pac.html is a tool that validates lots of aspects and explains why things have failed.

Comment: "Moved" to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18161/is-there-free-or-open-source-software-for-checking-pdf-a-compliance

Comment: http://verapdf.org/ is in the process of creating one.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A list of PDF/A validators is on the [pdfa.org](https://www.pdfa.org) web site here:

[verapdf](https://www.pdfa.org/new/verapdf-1-8-ships/)

A free online PDF/A validator is available here:

http://www.validatepdfa.com/

A report on the accuracy of many of these PDF/A validators is available from PDFLib:

https://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/pdfa/2009-05-04-Bavaria-report-on-PDFA-validation-accuracy.pdf

Se as well:

https://www.pdflib.com/knowledge-base/pdfa/

Comment: This one is open source https://github.com/gba-awl/padaf

Comment: Now known as PDFBox Preflight https://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.html#recent

Comment: Unfortunately the link at pdf.org is not available any more. At http://verapdf.org you will probably find the most "official" online tool for PDF validation. It is quite new and afaik in Beta. Until this changes I also stick with the preflight-validation of Adobe Acrobat

Answer (score 21):

The [3-Heights™ PDF Validator Online Tool](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx) provides good feedback for different [PDF/A conformance levels and versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A).

- PDF/A1-a
- PDF/A2-a
- PDF/A2-b
- PDF/A1-b
- PDF/A2-u

Comment: http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/pdf-validateur-pdfa-valider-iso.aspx

Comment: Free and no spam risk. +1 for this answer. thanks

Comment: Very nice.  This gives me a list of "violations" of PDF/A for my file, such as _The value of the key Parent is 271 0 R but must be 208 0 R._ But I have no idea how to "fix" these.  I tried saving in the free adobe acrobat but it doesn't help.

Comment: Here is something that just worked for me on my mac laptop: I opened my (ordinary) PDF file in the mac "Preview" software.  I "printed" it as a .ps file.  I then re-opened the .ps file in Preview and saved as PDF.  It now passes the pdf/a compliance.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, that was helpful! For those on Linux, I tried something similar which also worked: I opened the file on [evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince), and printed it to a PDF file. The resulting file passed PDF/A validation! Note that simply doing "File > Save as" was not sufficient; I had to use the Print menu for this to work.

Comment: The link seems dead unfortunately...

Comment: @a3nm Unfortunately the product is no longer available for free and requires a 30-day trial license. I will try to find another link that is similarly useful. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find one yet.

Answer (score 9):

pdf validation with OPEN validator:

DROID (Digital Record Object Identification) https://github.com/digital-preservation/droid/

JHOVE - JSTOR/Harvard Object Validation Environment https://jhove.openpreservation.org/

Comment: DROID doesn't validate, it only identifies. JHOVE does validate PDFs, but not PDF/A.

Comment: Jhove does validate PDF/A. Check there site: [link](http://jhove.sourceforge.net/pdf-hul.html)....

Comment: Ibn Saeed: citing from the linked doc: Note that the PDF module does not parse the contents on streams, so it cannot determine conformance to PDF/A to the degree required by the ISO standard.

Comment: @mykhal «That is not possible, since parts of the PDF/A rules are not machine-checkable AFAIK (like "metadata matches data" -- jhove is unable to understand the semantics of your document).» http://www.konradvoelkel.com/2013/03/scan-to-pdfa/#comment-2705

Comment: Jhove's PDF/A module is quite buggy. Its output is nearly meaningless.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have Adobe PDFL or Acrobat Professional? You can use preflight operation if you do.

Answer (score -6):

If you download the latest version of Adobe Acrobat Reader, it will tell you if your pdf is PDF/A compliant. Just open the PDF file and a big blue marking should appear.

OpenOffice supports PDF/A.
For some reason "PDF/A-1" is called

```
"SelectPdfVersion"
```

internally in OpenOffice.
Just add 1 to that value and your output should be PDF/A.

The different values can be

```
0 = PDFXNONE
1 = PDFX1A2001
2 = PDFX32002
3 = PDFA1A
4 = PDFA1B
```

You set

```
FilterData
```

to be a

```
HashMap('SelectPdfVersion',1) //1 for PDFX1A2001
```

Comment: This is wrong. The Reader show only if the PDF/A signature is available. Not if it is a valid PDF/A file.

Comment: @Horcrux7 can you site your sources for this? How do you know this? I have used a few API's that generate PDF/A and non PDF/A compliant files. When I produce a PDF/A file, Adobe Reader 10 will launch with an informational bar at top:O "The file you have opened complies with the PDF/A standard and has been opened read-only to prevent modification". Can you share what you know about this?L

Comment: We have write a software that generate PDF and PDF/A files (see my original posting). That I know that also not PDF/A compliance files was show as PDF/A file in Adobe Reader. We need only write the PDF/A signature.