# How to know if a document claims to be in PDF/A using itext7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7, pdfa

I had a function written using iText v5 and I'm trying to update it to use iText v7. The function checks if a document claims to be PDF/A (I know iText is not a PDF/A Validatior, I just need to know if it declares to be).

The implementation in v5 is the one from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028340/how-to-know-if-a-document-claims-to-be-in-pdf-a-using-itext). However, *reader.getMetadata()* method is no longer available in iText v7.

I've found that the reader in v7 provides a new method that looks perfect for that situation *getPdfAConformanceLevel*, but it is returning always null. After checking the [source code](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/kernel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfReader.java) I don't see where *pdfAConformanceLevel* is initialized, so I wonder, how does this work?

I've tried also reading the DocumentInformation, but without sucess.

My code is:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
PdfAConformanceLevel level = reader.getPdfAConformanceLevel();

if (level != null) {
    String conformance = level.getConformance();
    return "A".equalsIgnoreCase(conformance) || "B".equalsIgnoreCase(conformance);
}

return false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to get the conformance level.

**First way** is explicit - you do all the work manually and responsible for exception handling.

```
// Open the document
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filePath));

// Parse conformance level from metadata explicitly
byte[] existingXmpMetadata = pdfDocument.getXmpMetadata();
XMPMeta meta = XMPMetaFactory.parseFromBuffer(existingXmpMetadata);
PdfAConformanceLevel conformanceLevel = PdfAConformanceLevel.getConformanceLevel(meta);
```

**Second way** is indeed via `PdfReader`. You have identified this way correctly. The `conformanceLevel` field is set when the document is opened, so creating `PdfReader` only is not enough, you need to open the document:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filePath));
PdfAConformanceLevel conformanceLevel = pdfDocument.getReader().getPdfAConformanceLevel();
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Both methods produce exception when an instance of the reader is created if the file is not a pdf file.